# What does "wrong to the light" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Would you clarify the meaning of the words "wrong to the light" in this phrase (from a poem by Frost):

> "...having knelt at well-curbs, always wrong to the light, so never
>   seeing deeper down in the well than..."

Answer (score 4):

The speaker is kneeling before the stone wall that surrounds a water well. He's trying to see deep inside the well, but the sun is rarely at an angle that permits its light to illuminate the well's depths. The light isn't available: the light catches the well wrong (or conversely, the well is at the wrong angle to catch the light)." He's likely using this as a metaphor for our inability to get the deeper meaning out of things that we we want to understand.